# How to retrive the arguments passed during function call in LLVM?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I have a call instruction 'call void @calculate_output(i32 %14), !dbg !141' in llvm.
I want to retrieve the value object %14 from this.
Whenever, I am trying, I am getting the formal parameters for this instead of the actual parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting formal parameters, it means you are working with `Function*`, not `CallInst*`. Did you call `call->getFunction()`?

What you need is just `call->getArgOperand(0)`, see https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CallBase.html#ab2caa29167597390ab2fc3cf30d70389